# Error when defining a setter in ecmascript 6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, class, ecmascript-6, webstorm

I'm trying to define a class in ecmascript 6.

Here is the code :

```
class Machine {
   constructor (){
      this._context = null;
   }

   get context (){
      return this._context;
   }

   set context (context){
      this._context = context;
   }   
}
```

But I always get the same error for the setter in Webstorm :
"Set accessor method has type that is not compatible with get accessor type"

I don't understand why I get this error. I did exactly as explained here : http://es6-features.org/#GetterSetter

**EDIT** : It seems that the problem is only present because I defined my class in an angular factory.

So my question is how can I define a class properly in an angular factory ?

Maybe I'm not supposed to do it like that.

**EDIT 2** : Here is my angular factory :

```
angular.module('frontEndApp')
  .factory('Machine', function () {

     class Machine {
        constructor (){
           this._context = null;
        }

        get context (){
           return this._context;
        }

        set context (context){
           this._context = context;
        }   
     }

     return Machine;
  }
```

Comment: What version of WebStorm? [WebStorm 11](http://i.imgur.com/1mjspas.png) looks fine to me.

Comment: Same version here, no errors. Make sure your project is [set up to use ECMAScript 6 syntax](http://i.imgur.com/pgfXuMM.png).

Comment: I found that i only get the error if my class is defined in an angular service. Don't know how to define the class properly in an angular service

Comment: The issue is with your webstorm set up. it isnt related to angular or JS. your class declaration is good and returning it as an instance from a service is fine. something with your webstorm setup does not understand your code, which gives you 0 confidence in it as a tool because your code is good.

Comment: Yes but if I define the class in a common javascript file, webstorm doesn't point any issue. I only get the error in my angular factory

Comment: @GuillaumeRahbari: Your edit *completely changes* the question (and has a syntax error you should probably fix). It's usually frowned upon to completely change a question once it has answers.

Comment: I'm sorry for that, I was just trying to add more details. Do you know what is my syntax error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ES6 (ES2015) code is correct. Sounds like a bug in WebStorm around the new syntax (although the word "type" is surprising, as JavaScript is loosely typed; you might want to check that you don't have it set to TypeScript or similar).

Comment: It seems I don't, typescript is disabled and javascript is set to ECMAScript6

Comment: I just ran into this in PhpStorm. The setting in question is _JavaScript general errors_ in _Editor > Inspections > JavaScript > General_.

Answer (score 5):

I guess WebStorm cannot determine the type of the property `this._context`
You might want to annotate your code in order to help WebStorm (I had the same issue):

```
class Machine {
   constructor (){
      this._context = null;
   }

  /**
   * Proxy method for getting context.
   *
   * @return {ContextInterface}
   */
   get context (){
      return this._context;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the appropriate context.
    *
    * @param {ContextInterface} context
    */
   set context (context){
      this._context = context;
   }   
}
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. I've run into this on WebStorm with no-offending editor inspections set. I also had to use jsdoc style comments to type the get/set methods, and to make sure that those types are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with your Webstorm setup. Have you got a linter or something else running? Is it auto-detecting language and for some reason isnt picking JS?

The code is fine.

Comment: It seems i do not have linter, I disabled all check for javascript and i still get the error.